# How do I get rid of the margin on the bottom of my jumbotron in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a site for my high school robotics team and I am new to HTML and CSS (bootstrap). I do not want the space between my banner and my navbar  in my site. How do I eliminate that space?

www.robotichive3774.com

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Robotics Team 3774 Home</title>

<!-- Link to stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index1.css">


<!-- Mobile Scaling -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>
<!-------------------- UNIFORM CODE ------------------------->
<!-- Navbar -->

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Home">Team 3774</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="height: 0.866667px;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/Team Bio">Team Bio</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Our Robot">Our Robot</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Our Coach">Our Coach</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Outreach">Outreach</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Youtube">Youtube</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Banner -->
<div id="top-jumbotron" class="jumbotron">
    <img src="/Images/Banner.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
<!----------------------------------------------------------->

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Team 3774 Member Bio</h1>
    <p>Here you can find links to every member with some information on each of them.</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Abanoub Boules</h2>
            <p>Team Captain, Engineer, Coder, Mastur-bater</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Andre Bernardo</h2>
            <p>Head Engineer, Assistant Captain</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Leo Scarano</h2>
            <p>Head Coder, Head Web-master</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Kristen Kaldas</h2>
            <p>Coder, Head Documenter</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Anish Patel</h2>
            <p>Engineer, Head 3D Modelling</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Andrew Wojtkowski</h2>
            <p>Coder, Web-master, Engineer</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Furhan Ashraf</h2>
            <p>Financial Advisor, Engineer</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Kenneth Rebbecke</h2>
            <p>Engineer, Documenter</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</button>
        </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Mina Hanna</h2>
            <p>Engineer, Coder</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Melanie Aguilar</h2>
            <p>Secretary, Mascot</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set the margin-bottom to zero for the element:

```
#top-jumbotron { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

Example here: http://www.bootply.com/xQvinJhNLN

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS as shown above.  Or, you could use the classes that come with Bootstrap:

```
<jumbotron class="mb-0">
     <!-- Anything you are putting in the jumbotron -->
</jumbotron>
```

These classes can be used with various Bootstrap components.  Here is a link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/